# How can i secure cookie in php?

Tags: php, cookies

today i finished programming my project. 
and now i'm trying to find somebugs in my codes. 
i realize that when i want to change my info (like users) i can edit my user id from tamper data (ad-don to change header data) and i can change my level (from user to admin) via tamper date :/ 
this code i use for setting cookie

```
setcookie('level',$login['level'],time()+120*120*48);
setcookie('username',$login['username'],time()+120*120*48);
setcookie('uid',$login['uid'],time()+120*120*48);
```

i use $_COOKIE['uid'] when users try to add comment its come on database just a number (you know that)

and i want to give you this code i use it to start session and start in it every file.

```
include("cookiesset.php");
ob_start();
session_start();
if($_COOKIE['level'] != 1){
...
}else{
...
}
```

and this is cookie i have in header

```
uid=1; level=1; username=asd; PHPSESSID=ldr48bua487pjmtvohp53tr662; LoginForm=r9imqbnj2csfrmsu50i9kn0q54
```

ok how i can fix it ?
i want to secure my website.

if there is no solution i want to ask.

Comment: Then, stop using "uid" and level in cookies, create a table like "user_role" or something, then, create a cookie which contains an encrypted key for example `sha256('really_big_big_random_string')`, stores that value in a database so you can do something like: [key][uid][level][username] in the table (columns) select from that table where the key is the cookie value and then, get the results, so you don't show any important value in the cookie but with fetching them from a table is a little more secure.

Comment: @Asfo its very good idea. i will try it if there is no other solution

Comment: You could use an encryption directly in the cookie but still insecure because they can just "reverse" them (and with luck find the value so trade it)...I think is the more secure way if you really need those values, other option is to use SESSIONS if your cookies lives only meanwhile the user is on the site ...

Comment: Don't use cookies, use [sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/486/sessions#t=20170118000451962494).

Comment: @Asfo no your first idea is great, and cookie is good because you dont want to login for a long time and i dont know a lot of things about session, i just use session for my control panel with firewall.

Comment: Ok, I just added as another option...if it worked for you the first option, let me know :) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys about everything you gave it to me, 
i try to create a new column have a users key but its want more time to create and editing all files in project, i try to learn SESSION and how its work i found this 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp
Its so easy to learn,(in old, i think its not easy)

now i use

```
$_SESSION["level"] = $login['level'];
$_SESSION["username"] = $login['username'];
$_SESSION["uid"] = $login['uid'];
```

after i checked username and password from database

and this in files

```
ob_start();
session_start();
if($_SESSION['level'] != 1){
...
}else{
...
}
```

from tamper data and another tools,

```
PHPSESSID=d4i4itbp8p7ri4juvqd690t9a5
```

just i see PHPSESSID.

Thanks for all of you,
everything is great now and big thanks for @Asfo and @miken32 to give me a good advice.

i hope if there is anything wrong in my codes you edit it and helping me :)

**EDIT**

Thanks for everything 
but i realise when i delete (d4i4itbp8p7ri4juvqd690t9a5) from PHPSESSID i will have "file path disclosure" bug, 
i fixed it by put error_reporting(0); after session_start(); and everything will be alright for who want his script without bugs ;)

```
error_reporting(0);
ob_start();
session_start();
if($_SESSION['level'] != 1){
...
}else{
...
}
```